# Backbone-like router with dynamic regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, backbone.js, router

I've already written a PHP controller, but I'm rewriting my code so I can have Backbone Router-like JSON routes that map URI patterns to PHP Class::method combinations, or directly to HTML documents which are then delivered to the client, like so:

```
{
  "/home" : "index.html",
  "/podcasts": "podcasts.html",
  "/podcasts/:param1/:param2": "SomeClass::someMethod"
}
```

Backbone dynamically creates regexes to match routes against URLs. I took a look into the backbone code, and I extracted the following code (it's a bit modified):

```
function _routeToRegExp (route) {
  var optionalParam = /\((.*?)\)/g;
  var namedParam    = /(\(\?)?:\w+/g;
  var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
  var escapeRegExp  = /[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g;
  route = route.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
               .replace(optionalParam, '(?:$1)?')
               .replace(namedParam, function(match, optional){
                 return optional ? match : '([^\/]+)';
               })
              .replace(splatParam, '(.*?)');
  return new RegExp('^' + route + '$');
}
```

When I pass a route like `/podcasts/:param1/:param2`, to the code above, I get `/^\/podcasts\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/`. I was trying to write a PHP function to get exactly that same regex. I tried:

```
$route = '/podcasts/:param1/:param2';
$a = preg_replace('/[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/', '\\$&', $route); // escapeRegExp
$b = preg_replace('/\((.*?)\)/', '(?:$1)?', $a);                // optionalParam
$c = preg_replace('/(\(\?)?:\w+/', '([^\/]+)', $b);             // namedParam
$d = preg_replace('/\*\w+/', '(.*?)', $c);                      // splatParam
$pattern = "/^{$d}$/";
echo "/^\/podcasts\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/\n";
echo "{$pattern}\n";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, '/podcasts/param1/param2', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

My output is:

```
/^\/podcasts\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/    // The expected pattern
/^/podcasts/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)$/       // echo "{$pattern}\n";
Array                                 // print_r($matches);
(
)
```

Why is my regex output different? I can handle the rest of the mapping process and all, but I haven't figured out how to obtain exactly the same regex in PHP as in Javascript. Any suggestions?

Comment: It got too frustrating, so a colleague helped me write a very convenient nodeJs function that returns that regex via CLI. If I find a way to do this in PHP, I'll certainly post the correct answer. :)

Comment: Easy fix: use ~ for delimiting the regex - i.e. ~pattern~ rather than /pattern/. That way you don't have to escape the / characters. It makes the regex a bit easier to read as well.

Answer (score 2):

The JS version does not in fact escape the / chars, it produces the same string representation as your PHP version  `/podcasts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)` but, and that's probably what tripped you, a `console.log` of the regexp returned by  `_routeToRegExp` shows the full representation with the delimiting / and the inner ones escaped :

```js
//Firefox output
RegExp /^\/podcasts\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/w6zP2/ for a demo.

What @ajshort noted in the comments and what Backbone does are the same solution : skip the / escaping and use an alternative syntax; Backbone does it with an explicit call to the Regexp constructor with `new RegExp('^' + route + '$')`, you can do something similar with `$pattern = "~^{$d}$~";`

And a PHP Fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4de-jf3 that seems to work as expected.

Note that in Javascript `$&` in a replacement string inserts the matched substring<sup>1</sup>, not so in PHP<sup>2</sup>. The escapeRegExp should be modified and might look like :

```php
$a = preg_replace('/[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#~\s]/', '\\\\$0', $route);
```

which gives us an updated code:

```php
$a = preg_replace('/[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#~\s]/', '\\\\$0', $route); // escapeRegExp
$b = preg_replace('/\((.*?)\)/', '(?:$1)?', $a);                // optionalParam
$c = preg_replace('/(\(\?)?:\w+/', '([^\/]+)', $b);             // namedParam
$d = preg_replace('/\*\w+/', '(.*?)', $c);                      // splatParam
$pattern = "~^{$d}$~";

echo "/^\/podcasts\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/\n";
echo "{$pattern}\n";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, '/podcasts/param1/param2', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

<sup>1</sup> See *Specifying a string as a parameter* in [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
<sup>2</sup> See *replacement* in [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Tried that phpfiddle example, and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot, @nikoshr. I'll work on the code and post the full example somewhere as soon as I'm done with some further testing and all. It was kind of awkward working with that nodeJs function anyway! :D

Comment: @Óscar Palacios Glad it helped :)